# Trying to create big table in excel

Tags: excel, database, performance, datatable

I want to create a pretty big table in excel.
I have 4000 rows and 70 columns, I have images that are locked into cells as well.
Do I have a chance this table creation process will work, or will excel be stuck?

Is there a workaround maybe?

any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel doesn't have a hard cap on it's rows / column count (well it does but it's astronomical), although once reaching certain thresholds, it might be preferable to move towards a database solution. Have you considered creating a small MySql server instead of using excel files?

For excel limitations see : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/data-model-specification-and-limits-19aa79f8-e6e8-45a8-9be2-b58778fd68ef